# Display:none; not working in css

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I'm using this script below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".btn-slide").hover(function() {
        $("#panel").slideDown(500);
    });


    $("#loginstuff").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#panel").slideUp(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

It creates a box when you hover over a link.

Now the CSS is like this:

```
#panel {
    display:none;
    margin:80px 0 0 0;
    width:180px;
    background:#000;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:7px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    display:block;
    word-spacing: 0px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

It's suppose to hide the panel div, and the script is suppose to show the div on hover.

The only problem is that the div still displays on page load, can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Your HTML code could help more understanding the structure.

Answer (score 10):

You have `display: none` on the first line and then you have `display: block` further down the block.
Have you tried removing the second one?

Answer (score 5):

you are adding `display:none;` and then at bottom of css `display:block;` so its getting overridden,  remove following line from your css for #panel:

```
display:block;
```